# how to expose public methods of member variables in JS

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a class

```
function A()
{
   var that = this;
   var b = new B(); 
   this.setBSize = function(newSize)
   {
      b.setSize(newSize);
   }


};

function B()
{
   var that = this;

   this.setSize = function(newSize)
   {
   ...
   }
}

a = new A();
a.setBSize(5);
```

How do I avoid writing the setBSize method? How do I expose the public methods of b automatically? I want to do the call like this

```
a.setSize(5);
```

**Also I need a reference to `new B();` which is b inside `A()`**

Comment: Maybe the following answer will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 3):

You could always set the prototype of `A` to `B` if you want to inherit all the methods in `B`

```
function A() {
    var that = this;
};

function B() {
    var that = this;

    this.setSize = function (newSize) {
        console.log(newSize); // 5
    }
}

A.prototype = new B();

a = new A();
a.setSize(5);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/njz6h2b4/1/)

Comment: To avoid invoking the constructor you can use `Object.create`. `A.prototype = new B();` -> `A.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);` which can help when you have an abstract base class.

Answer (score 2):

In `jQuery`: `$.extend(that, new B());`
In `angular`: `angular.extend(that, new B());`

```
function A()
{
   var that = this;
   $.extend(that, new B());
};

function B()
{
   var that = this;

   this.setSize = function(newSize)
   {
   ...
   }
}

a = new A();
a.setSize(5);
```

And if you want to use any `private` variables in `B()` class define them as `var someVar`, and all public (overridable) variables as `that.somePublicVar`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method for this:

```
function A() {
    var that = this;
    B.call(this);
};

function B() {
    var that = this;
    this.setSize = function (newSize) {
        this.size = newSize;
    }
}

var a = new A();
a.setSize(5);
```

Basically you invoke `B` in context of `A`, and what happens is that all own properties of the `B` instance are going to be assigned to `this` which is `A` instance. This pattern is called constructor or methods borrowing.

Answer (score 1):

You should utilize prototyping.

make a constructor which shares the function among all the classes(objects):

```
var myConstructor = function(newSize){

   this.setSize = function(newSize)
   {
   ...
   }
}
```

Now you do instanciation:

```
var a = new myConstructor(someSize);

var b = new myConstrucotr(someSize);
```

Now with this change `a.setSize()` is the same as `b.setSize()`

Answer (score 1):

Using prototype for inheriting the method `setSize` and discarding all the `this` and `that` code.

```
function B() {
};
function A() {
    B.call(this);
};

B.prototype.setSize = function(newSize) {
    console.log(newSize);
}

A.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);
A.prototype.constructor = A;
var a = new A();
a.setSize(5);               // 5
console.log(a instanceof A);// true
console.log(a instanceof B);// true
```